# How to just show front page and message when search api search was queried with blank input

Tags: search

How can I just show front page when no letters were printed in search input, but it was submitted?

And optionally maybe show message 'please enter the terms of the search'

I thought of doing this with Rules, but no rules considering searches are present(

Comment: u have to look into form alter hook.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
function MY_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if($form_id == 'search_block_form' || $form_id == 'search_form') {
    array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'custom_search_validate');
  }
}

function custom_search_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state);
  if(isset($form_state['values']['search_block_form']) && $form_state['values']['search_block_form'] == FALSE) {
    drupal_set_message('please enter the terms of the search', 'error');
    drupal_goto();
  }

  if(isset($form_state['values']['keys']) && $form_state['values']['keys']
    == FALSE) {
    drupal_set_message('please enter the terms of the search', 'error');
    drupal_goto();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. your answer is pretty OK, but few words of explanation for the readers not fluent with hooks, form api and module writing could significantly improve it.

Comment: @Mołot Sorry. I'll consider it. I edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambrusco.Newbie I'm glad to help you.